# Antenna Design for specific directions

Tags: design, antenna, physics, pcb-antenna, physical-design

I am designing an antenna for a device and was hoping to gain some insight in the correct design direction for the antenna.

**The Idea:**
A receiver & antenna that fits in a 6" diameter by 3" deep cylinder.

**Known:**
Frequencies range from 162.400 to 162.550 MHz.
The signal will not be coming directly from the top or bottom.

**Goals:**
Design the *“best”* antenna I can given my knowledge of the direction the signal will be coming from, the size constraint of the enclosure and the frequency.

Any advice, recommendations, and/or help would be greatly appreciated. I am specifically interested in the physical layout/design of the antenna.(For example coil wire cylinder)

**Thoughts:** My gut feeling is to enclose the maximum area possible with the antenna. From my initial research the length is not as important as I had previously thought which lead me to start to ponder this even more.

[image]

**Notes:** I like math if you are so inclined :)

**Additional questions answered:**

- Between 75 and 90 degrees and also between 0 and -90 degrees I dont
  expect a signal in that region.
- The environment for operation of the antenna is inside a home about
  ceiling height(8-12 feet).
- This antenna is intended for receive only.
- It is feeding into a IC receiver.
- Input impedance (50 ohms)
- The signal is coming from miles away
- The source is the NOAA weather radio all hazards broadcast
- The frequency is not changeable

Comment: Not my area so I'll not answer, but a few general observations: 1) Looks like the radiation pattern for a vertical. 2) Your frequency range has a wavelength of (I believe) appx 6 ft, so a 3 inch vertical sounds awfully short. 3) You may have a better response on http://ham.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Tut Thanks! Could you elaborate on #1 and +1 specifically for #3 :) didn't even know this existed.

Comment: 1) I think you'll see what I mean if you Google "vertical antenna radiation pattern". Regarding 2) I believe vertical antennas are typically 1/4 wavelength, but I think they can be made shorter with coils. Again ... not my area of expertise. 3) You could probably get a moderator to migrate this if you wish. ... Good luck!

Comment: "gain some insight" pun intended? haha!I am interested in the answer to this one. *favourited*

Comment: @KyranF :) you know

Comment: Cross-post with http://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/2198/antenna-design-for-specific-directions

Comment: @Tut that site being in beta is this ok? What should I do? Never ran into an issue were I am torn 50-50 where the post should reside. I am thinking here simply due to the difference in activity.

Comment: Probably a question for a moderator (or Meta). I just mentioned the cross-post because I knew there were others who "favorited" the question. You could try clicking on "chat" and selecting "Ask a moderator". It doesn't bother me.

Comment: I'm thinking "folded dipole" but I'm drinking vodka and that doesn't help much.

Comment: @Andyaka - vodka + antenna design = ? :)

Comment: I'm sober now and I think it'll work but look up the curved version then base load with inductors to reduce physical size.

Comment: @Tut the problem with the vertical is obviously won't fit. So then the question becomes how do u modify a vertical to make it work. My thought would be a coil... So wider coil full wave length or smaller coil 1/4 wave length... I wish I had some math to do here.

Comment: @Andyaka could you elaborate on, "base load with inductors to reduce the physical size"

Comment: Yeah, this is getting beyond my knowledge. I like the idea of the [small loop antenna](http://ham.stackexchange.com/a/2200/590). I wonder what a 6' loop would do wound on your 6" diameter? Despite what intuition may tell you, I think the radiation pattern for a small loop may be correct.

Comment: Read down this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whip_antenna and look for a section called "Electrically short whips". It explains that base loading with an inductor can reduce antenna size from optimum. It can be applied to a curved folded dipole such as this http://www.antiference.co.uk/sitefiles/antiference/FM1080%20Aerial.jpg.

Comment: @Andyaka - Small loop thoughts: Current confusion - Why do standard AM radio antenna sit up right? Why not lay them down if the radiation pattern is in the plane of the coil? [AM antenna img](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8b/Loop_Antenna.jpg/250px-Loop_Antenna.jpg)

Comment: That looks like a magnetic loop antenna for around the 1MHz sort of tuning range. I don't think that is a dipole antenna folded, curved or not.

Comment: Cross-posted on ham.SE, where it already has an answer. [Cross-posting is strongly discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu), so I vote this one closed.

Comment: @PhilFrost If you read the first answer in the link you posted it suggest that sites living past beta are unknown. So even though cross posting is discouraged and the question may better fit there I believe the site being in beta is grounds for this so that the information is not lost provided it is closed. Quote from your link "Note: I do not consider any sites valid migration targets until they are out of public beta. There are no guarantees that a current SE site will live past beta." Side note: I am curious where you beleive this question belongs. The answer on ham SE has zero knowledge bg

Comment: @tman It is confusing indeed but I have been watching the Amateur Radio SE and the knowledge level of the moderators seems adequate. Perhaps the beta on AR could be lifted? In regards to your antenna question, I believe that a short vertical (rubber ducky) antenna would fit the radiation pattern but for better signal to noise (on receive) a loop antenna would not only be quieter but it would also not require the antenna to be squeezed due to the space constraints given.

Comment: @tman, it says beta sites aren't migration targets. I don't interpret that as "so you should cross-post on beta sites". If ham.SE doesn't live past beta, its questions will be merged into here. And, you already have an answer there. If you aren't satisfied with those answers, you should ask for clarification in the comments or by editing your question. And, this one has been sitting over a week without an answer. I'm not sure what you are hoping to accomplish.

Answer (score 5):

### Additional specifications as clarified by "tman"

- Signal is not expected between *75deg and 90 deg* and also between *0deg and -90deg* elevation, and rejection in these sectors is not explicitly required. An omni-directional antenna is an acceptable solution.
- The antenna is to be used indoors in a fixed installation -- inside a home at about ceiling height.
- This antenna is intended for receive only.

### The classic monopole

A simple vertical whip antenna (the conventional straight up wire in the air over ground) will produce almost exactly what you want.

This is my model of a dipole radiator. It consists of one wire sticking up from the origin and one going down (ergo "di"pole). If you use a monopole (e.g. just one wire going up) you can eliminate the portion of the graph below the z=0 plane.

[image]

I drew the transparent plane in it for reference so you can imagine it in 2D. If you think about the intersection-curve in my plane, without the lower half, you get a radiation power density that looks almost exactly like your figure.

Namely, a double hump with radiation going outwards and a null when looking down on the antenna from directly overhead (90deg elevation) and not really showing much signal strength until you are some degrees away from directly overhead (~75deg, let's say).

The problem with this antenna type is that peak efficiency occurs for 1/4 the wavelength. Since your wavelength is huge (3e8/162.5e6*100/2.54/12 = 6 feet) relative to the size of your antenna (3 inches), no antenna of this type will radiate well in the far-field. The matching will be very poor.

You can use techniques proposed in the comments such as "inductive loading" to improve the matching, but all this does is make the antenna *appear* electrically longer than it is physically. It doesn't really increase the proportion of energy radiated into the universe. Instead it prevents the leftover energy (the stuff that didn't radiate) from "bouncing" off the end of the antenna (by converting it to heat in the load inductors) and returning to damage the transmitter or corrupt the received signal. You just can't build a practical antenna of this type at this size for your application.

As to directivity (and meeting your requirement not to transmit/receive below zero elevation), in general, the larger the ground plane is, the lower the direction of maximum radiation. As the ground plane approaches infinite size, the radiation pattern approaches a maximum in the x-y plane. If you suspend your antenna in the air or use a 6" diameter disk at the base of your antenna for a ground (reference) plane, the amount of power radiated straight out will be less than ideal.

### Folded Unipole (Monopole) Antennas

The Folded Unipole Antenna (FUA) is just the monopole antenna previously described folded over so that it makes a theoretical U-shape like so:

[image]

The top doesn't have be just a wire, you can put impedance up there, and, likewise, you can do the same at the "bottom" where the folded-over aerial returns to the ground.

This makes the situation much more complex because now you have self-induced interactions between current in both vertical legs. These interactions can be resonant in a way that creates an overall current (common-mode) and a net difference in current between the legs (differential-mode). I did this analysis when I was working on ways to build smaller low-frequency antennas to help ocean buoys call home.

[image]

As you can see there are now multiple potential operating points and they are at locations that are unconventional for a simple monopole. You can get them to radiate efficiently both shorter and longer than the 1/4 wavelength length of the monopole or the 1/2 wavelength antenna length of the dipole. FUA's offer a large set of knobs you can tune such as top and bottom impedance, and the characteristic impedance of the up and down legs themselves.

There is much space to explore there and it is quite possible you could achieve something with an FUA variant, but this will take serious commitment on your part. There is no "online antenna calculator" that will yield an instant solution (at least as far as I'm aware, obviously).

### Coils

If you compress each turn of the coil, so that they are close together instead of looking more like a corkscrew, you will not excite the TEM mode of the antenna and therefore you will not get the traditional gun-like pattern (highly directive pattern with the peak emission along the coil's axis). Instead it will just behave like a horribly tuned monopole (with lots of reactance and low radiation resistance).

Coils will not help you get more radiation out of your volume simply by packing more wire into the limited available volume.

### To the first order

Almost every antenna attempting this spec will be bad. So which is a little more bad or less bad may not be worth the significant effort it will take to design and differentiate them.

Most consumer AM antennas are also bad, but they are receive only. Bad receive-only antennas are necessarily ineffective recipients of energy and so do not have to worry about being overpowered or suffering from the bad power match to the receiver. The AM broadcast system compensates for limited antenna performance on the receive side by using insanely great (random Apple reference!) amounts of transmit power (tens of thousands of watts!).

Comment: This is why I love the site. Your questions:Is it that you need to reject signals between 75deg and 90 deg and also between 0deg and -90deg elevation, or that there just simply isn't any input signal there? I dont expect my signal in that region.

Where are you going to operate this antenna and in what environment (is it installed on a car roof, sitting on the ground, etc...)? Inside a home about ceiling height.

Is this antenna intended for transmit, receive, or both?Only receive!

What is it feeding? It is feeding into a receiver. Can you elaborate on what you are asking here?

Comment: @tman -- What are you using for your receiver? Do you have a spec for that? If it's an indoor application, I assume that you don't need long-range. Why are you using such a low frequency?

Comment: I am using a IC for the receiver. I'll assume my specs you are referring to input impedance (50 ohms). I have no problem handling the impedance matching segment of the design. The antenna is indoor, however, the signal is coming from miles away. The frequency is the NOAA weather radio all hazards broadcast.

Comment: Ah. Makes sense. That's very helpful. I'll think about it. Might take me a few days.

Comment: I would really appreciate it! Sorry for the lack of detail from the start...I had hoped to not dilute the main question, but I fear I may have anyways...Again thanks for your interest in helping! THANK YOU.

Comment: Given your comment, "Almost every antenna attempting this spec will be bad. So which is a little more bad or less bad may not be worth the significant effort it will take to design and differentiate them." What design would you go with? My current choice is a [small loop antenna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_antenna#Small_loops)

Comment: You could try a folded dipole - made from aluminium foil. A 6" diameter gives a circumference of 18.8" so take a strip of foil 2.5" wide by 36" long. Put some insulating plastic (cling wrap?) 18" long in the centre, fold the ends of the foil over: one folded dipole. Now bend it in a curve, it should fit in the space you specified.  Whatever you end up with, TEST IT by using a small transmitter nearby in assorted locations, and plot signal strength. If you have a solution that satisfies, show everyone in a follow-up posting.

Comment: @Alan -- That's very interesting, but curving it into the circumference will add top-termination and detune it. I'm curious to see if it works as well. I might try it this evening if I get a moment.

Comment: @DrFriedParts I would love to hear your thoughts on using a small loop antenna.

Comment: @tman are you referring to a magnetic loop antenna? The design specs I can find on the Internet seem to only deal with transmitting, and in the HF band. However, there's a few 2m TX antennas that look the right size & shape, so technically it should be possible.

Comment: @AlanCampbell im referring to the following [antenna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_antenna#Small_loops) which states, " Small loop antennas are much less than a wavelength in size, and are mainly (but not always) used as receiving antennas at lower frequencies. The small loop antenna is also known as a magnetic loop since it behaves electrically as a coil (inductor) with a small but non-negligible radiation resistance due to its finite size" This seems like what I am shooting for!